# Create React App on Firebase breaks all my Express endpoints on frontend

Tags: reactjs, express, firebase, create-react-app

I'm having problems with accessing Express endpoints on Firebase hosting when using a Create React App production build.

The only change I made to `firebase.json` was switching from the default `public` folder to `create-react-app/build`.

When I go to `example.com/test` in browser, using Create React App in production, it just redirects me back to index, but using a separate REST client I'm still able to access that endpoint.

If I switch back to the default `public` folder in `firebase.json` and deploy to production, accessing this endpoint from the browser still works as well, but I no longer have Create React App of course.

What is happening here?  Any help is appreciated.

---

UPDATE:  It has something to do with service workers.  I was able to find a temporary workaround by commenting out:

`import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';`

and

`registerServiceWorker();`

from `src/index.js`.

Then I went to Chrome developer tools and "unregistered" the service worker from the Application menu.

Now I'm wondering how to correctly implement service workers.

Answer (score 0):

It may be happen, because when you done `firebase init`, last question from console was something like - make a single page app (redirect all URL  to index.html).
So what you can do, is to tun `firebase init` again, and select in this option NO.
And make deploy again.